# sed: unknown option to `s'

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I am trying to use a shell script file in the Bash shell. In this script, 2 `sed` commands are there. The second `sed` command is following.

```
sed -e s:MACRO_NAME:"${runmacro}":g \
    -e s:INFILE_PATH_NAME:"${filedir}"/"${filename}":g \
    -e s:INFILE_NAME:"${filename%.*}":g \
    -e s:INDEX:"${index}":g \
    -e s:TREE_NAME:"${treename}":g \
    -e s:SUFFIX:"${suffix}":g \
    -e s:SMEAR_TEMPLATE_NAME:"${smeartemplatename}":g \
    -e s:IS_MC:"${ismc}":g \
    -e s:PWD:.:g \
    -e s:SCRAM_DIR:"${scramdir}":g \
    -e s:OUTFILE_NAME:"${outfilename}":g \
    -e s:OUTFILE_DIR:"${outputpath}":g \
    -e s:PREFIX:"${prefix}":g \
    -e s:OUTPUT_DIR:"${outputdir}":g \
        template_files/submit_script_template.sh > tempfile \
&& mv tempfile ../"${outputdir}"/submit_"${outputdir}"_"${index}".sh
```

By executing the `.sh` file, I am getting this error:

```
sed: -e expression #2, char 25: unknown option to `s'
```

I added `echo` to `sed` also. The result is:

```
sed -e s:MACRO_NAME:QCDSmearedSkimmer.C:g \
    -e s:INFILE_PATH_NAME:root://cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/lpcstop/noreplica/13TeV/290117/Moriond17/qcd_orig//qcd_ht1000to1500-ext_10_ntuple_postproc.root:g \
    -e s:INFILE_NAME:qcd_ht1000to1500-ext_10_ntuple_postproc:g \
    -e s:INDEX:2:g \
    -e s:TREE_NAME:Events:g \
    -e s:SUFFIX:SmearedQCD:g \
    -e s:SMEAR_TEMPLATE_NAME:resTailOut_combined_filtered_CHEF_puWeight_weight_WoH.root:g \
    -e s:IS_MC:1:g \
    -e s:PWD:.:g \
    -e s:SCRAM_DIR:${CMSSW_BASE}:g \
    -e s:OUTFILE_NAME:qcd_ht1000to1500-ext_10_ntuple_postproc_1_SmearedQCD.root:g \
    -e s:OUTFILE_DIR:/ddash/nobackup/mywork/qcd/CMSSW_9_4_6_patch1/src/AnalysisMethods/macros/Skims/generate_smear_scripts/smeared_file/:g \
    -e s:PREFIX:root://cmseos.fnal.gov//:g \
    -e s:OUTPUT_DIR:qcd_smeared_file3:g \
        template_files/submit_script_template.sh > tempfile \
&& mv tempfile ../qcd_smeared_file3/submit_qcd_smeared_file3_2.sh
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: `"${filedir}"` or `"${filename}"` probably has a `:` in it.

Comment: From this file dir it will take filename.So  i think, "/"  will be there.

Comment: @Melebius The OP prepended `echo` to the sed call and added the results to the question as requested, so I think this question is not unclear anymore.

Comment: `root://cmseos` <- right there is the `:` in `"${filedir}"/"${filename}"`.

Comment: Here "root://cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/lpcstop/noreplica/13TeV/290117/Moriond17/qcd_orig/" is filedir and "qcd_orig//qcd_ht1000to1500-ext_10_ntuple_postproc.root" is the file name.This file is inside this directory.

Comment: What can you change here? Can you change the script? Can you change the input (these variables)?

Comment: Yes I can change the script and the input variable.But I am not getting , the error is showing because of what?How can I fix this error..The error is "sed: -e expression #2, char 25: unknown option to `s'"

Answer (score 3):

In the sed expression `s:INFILE_PATH_NAME:"${filedir}"/"${filename}":g`, there are five parts:

- the `sed` command `s`,
- the search pattern for that command (`INFILE_PATH_NAME`),
- the replacement text (whatever `"${filedir}"/"${filename}"` - in this example, that's `root://cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/lpcstop/noreplica/13TeV/290117/Moriond17/qcd_orig//qcd_ht1000to1500-ext_10_ntuple_postproc.root`),
- options to the `s` command (here `g`),
- and the delimiter that separates all these, which is `:` (colon) here.

Now, if the replacement text contains `:`, then sed will think that the replacement text ends there, and whatever follows are options to `s`. So instead of

- replacement: `root://cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/lpcstop/noreplica/13TeV/290117/Moriond17/qcd_orig//qcd_ht1000to1500-ext_10_ntuple_postproc.root`
- option: `g`,

we get:

- replacement: `root`
- option: `//cmseos.fnal.gov//store/user/lpcstop/noreplica/13TeV/290117/Moriond17/qcd_orig//qcd_ht1000to1500-ext_10_ntuple_postproc.root:g`

which is invalid as far as sed is concerned.

Suggested solutions:

1. use a different delimiter, some character which won't appear in the replacement text, such as `,` (comma), `;` (semicolon), etc. For example:

   ```
   sed -e "s,INFILE_PATH_NAME,${filedir}/${filename},g" ...
   ```
2. Wherever you get your input from, escape `:` with a backslash so that it becomes `\:`.

Comment: @DipikaDash If not already done, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). But don't feel urged. Just take your time.

Comment: Small addition to point 2., the escaping in case of `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `yash` and other modern shells (not `dash`) would be just: `sed -e "s:INFILE_PATH_NAME:${filedir//:/\\:}/${filename//:/\\:}:g" ...`

Answer (score 2):

The error appears because your variables (at least some of them) contain colons (`:`) and you use a colon as the delimiter for the `s/…/…/` command. Actually for the `s:…:…:` command in your case.

When you have

```
var="ex:ample"
```

and then try to issue

```
sed -e "s:${var}:sample:g" some_file
```

then the shell interpolates the variable before handing it over to `sed`, and `sed` is called like so:

```
sed -e "s:ex:ample:sample:g" some_file
```

and the `s:…:…:` is now broken. It looks like you are telling `sed` to replace `ex` with `ample` and apply the options `s`, `a`, `m`, `p`, `l`, and `e`.

To avoid this, use a different delimiter which you are sure of it doesn't appear in your text. Popular delimiters are `+` and `#` but you can choose any character. The delimiter is in fact the first character after the `s`, so

```
sed -e "s#…#…#" some_file
sed -e "s+…+…+" some_file
sed -e "s'…'…'" some_file
```

will all do.

Comment: @PerlDuck.Sorry for the late comment.Thank you so much for your help. It is the answer worked for me.